# Actionscript: Multiline text fields and bottom padding

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am creating a text field using

```
multiline = isMultiLine;
wordWrap = true;
```

I am setting the height of the text field using

```
_tf.height = _tf.height * _tf.numLines;
```

Because if I do not not the additional lines do not appear and you have to click on them the drag to see them.

The above code works, however the padding at the bottom of the _tf.height gets larger as the number of lines increase. So I think this is because my input height is getting multiplied by the number of lines.

However, I am using the minimum _tf.height value, if I reduce it then all the lines overlap.

I also tried manually setting the _tf.height later on to remove the extra padding, however this resulted in the same overlap issue.

How can I remove the bottom padding?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#autoSize

*If autoSize is set to TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT ... If wordWrap is also set to true, only the bottom of the text field is resized and the right side remains fixed.*

```
TextFiel.wordWrap = true;
TextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work better than mulitplying by number of lines

```
tf.width = DESIRED_WIDTH;
tf.multiline = isMultiLine;
tf.wordWrap = true;
tf.text = yourText;
tf.height = tf.textHeight + DESIRED_PADDING;
```

textHeight will tell you the actual height used by the glyphs contained within.  Usually you want at least a few pixels of padding or it could clip you just a bit.